# Transparent Popup / Overlay with Buttons (JQuery, CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a html website and I want to see on my mainpage a transparent overlay / popup with buttons like in the picture I uploaded. To press one of these buttons for redirection to particular url. How can I create this popup? It should be universal, therewith I don't need to change my html structure and also I can use it with different websites by just binding this JQuery/CSS.

My sketch:

[image]

Comment: Use `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` on the wrapping element of the buttons. If you will not define background, it will be transparent (not sure about old browsers)

Comment: @Morpheus Should I draw this popup with canvas/css? Or do I have create HTML elements with jquery? This overlay/popup should work by just binding jquery+css. Do you have a good apposite example?

Comment: Here is a quick example https://jsfiddle.net/aLanq5qa/

Comment: @Morpheus Thank you. I will try to extend it and make it as in my picture. I'm not sure if I can do it because of lack of experience. But your example will take me further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up an example on ho wto accomplish this.  You can use the `rgba` to add alpha (or transparency) into your colors.

```js
$("body").append(`<div class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li>Ex 1</li>
    <li>Ex 2</li>
    <li>Ex 3</li>
    <li>Ex 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>`)
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.popup {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(77,77,77,.4);
}

.popup > ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width:100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.popup > ul > li {
  background:green;
  display:inline-block;
  color:black;
  border:2px solid black;
  width:calc(25% - 8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't change my html site directly, but I can create this new div and li-buttons with JQeury, right? Will js-event handler work with js-generated li-elements? If you could extend your example with JQuery it would be great! (generate div + event handler for it)

Comment: @MeteorNewbie is that what you meant?

Comment: `$( ".popup" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});`